# Hide table column with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, selector

This was asked many times, I know but this is different! I made this:

[image]

When you click on the minus icon, the column should disappear, this worked with php, but the code is a mess and I would like to get this working with jQuery, i found some other threads that showed me this:

```
$("#minus").click(function() {
    $("#table td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)").hide();
});
```

After a while I came up with this:

```
var num = $("#columnid").index();    
$("#table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").hide();
```

That kinda worked, but i need to call it with a `onclick="jquery_function();"` function and let php insert the id of every header, but is this possible? Or what is the other way of doing this? i'm stuck!

**This did it:**

```
$(".minus").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    $("#table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").fadeOut(250);
});
```

Seems simple after figuring out, Jeroen had it right. :) The only thing i dont get is why you need the ("th"), works with and without. Thanks!

Comment: Datatables.net can show/hide columns two ways, http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html and http://datatables.net/extras/colvis/ which has state saving

Comment: Do you mean echoing out the ID inside of the `<td>` tags?  That'd pretty much just be `<td id="<?= $id; ?>">` if that's all you need...  But I don't think that's it.  Can you explain what you need a little more?

Comment: The idea was to use jQuery like javascript.. like this: onclick="someFunction(<?php echo $something ?>);" but the way the other guys suggested was more jQuery'ish. :)

Comment: @Gideon I added the `th` because I did not know whether the `th` was the direct parent of your button; there could have been div's or span's in your table cell, so using `.parents("th")` I looked for the nearest `th` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've almost got it complete. What you could do, is wrap it in a function and attach the event handler to the button in the table header cell:

```
$("th .button").click(function(){
  var num = $(this).parents("th").index();    // untested, but something like this should do it
  $("#table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").hide();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so I will just need to make the var num a bit more dynamic, thanks for the idea, will try in a min!

Comment: @Gideon Exactly, you don't need the ID, you just need to find out in which `th` was clicked on the button.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
// note the class for multiple minus
$(".minus").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var index = $('.minus').index($this); // get the zero based index of this element
  index++; // adjust for zero based index
  var selector = '#table td:nth-child(' + index + '), the:nth-child(' + index + ')';
  $(selector).hide();
});
```

Untested, and feel free to omit code as you see fit.

Comment: Seeing the working code i have now, this should work. It only seems so messy, but maybe thats me. Thanks though!