# Animating a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fade

I asked a question yesterday on here and got some awsome help, but I need more help concerning more or less the same, only a bit different.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702641/hide-table-column-with-jquery) is my old thread.

So ye, I made this and the idea is that you can customize the table to see it the way you want. for now its possible to drag the columns to change the order and its possible to order the columns on alphabet or high/low. Since I got help here, its now also possible to hide the columns.

Now I want to make the hiding process a bit more smooth, since its hard to see if something is hidden after a click if you use no animation. I use .fadeOut(200); now, but when the fading is done the column just 'jumps' to fill the gap, is it possible to animate this in some sort?

Edit: After thinking some more, I thought that I could just loop a -1px width untill the element's width is 1px and then just hide it, but for some reason that wont work, the table doesnt respond to .width(xxx); or .css('width', 'xxx');. It does change the value, but the td keeps the same width.

Comment: reduce the time from `200` to `100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of a workaround, and there might be a better solution, but here it is anyway:

1. Animate the opacity to 0.0. Fadeout does the same, but it also sets `display:none` after completely fading out. It is the `display:none`  that causes the adjacent column to jump and fill in the gap.
2. Animating will cause your hidden div to remain there. Now that it is no longer visible, animate its width to 0. This will cause the adjacent div to smoothly take over its place.
3. Once width is 0, set `display:none`

Here's a working sample I whipped up. Adjust accordingly to animate width: http://jsfiddle.net/x7BEv/8/

Here's how the magic happens:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#upper').animate({opacity:0.0},'slow').animate({height:'0px'},'slow',allDone);
    });
});

function allDone()
{
    $('#upper').hide();
}
```

I'm not sure how important the `allDone()` method is. You could probably do away with it.

Comment: Just made an edit about this, I need to type faster. :p But ye, seems a good idea, but how do I animate the width to 0? As I said, I tried looping but doesnt work.

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work, atleast not with a table I think. Nice site btw, just made something: http://jsfiddle.net/Gideonnn/ePvxL/ The thing is, it works kinda good in there, but if I use exactly the same on my site, the with thing doesnt work.

Comment: It works pretty good in your jsfiddle. Try to set border (`border:1px black solid;`) to the columns to see where exactly the problem is. It makes it easy to debug CSS issues. Maybe you're reducing the width of a div within a td, but not the td itself?

Comment: Also I tried to edit the allDone function to work with my script (it needs a variable to be passed with it) it does work, but with no animation at all, it gets instantly hidden. Weird.. cant find out whats causing it.

Comment: it is possible some other style is overriding the width you set. Change to `style="opacity:0;width:0 !important"` and try. If that works, you can edit the jquery similarly as well `$(selector).animate({width:'0px !important'},'slow');`

Comment: Nop, not working, this is killing me! Even if I set the css manually to width: 150px !important; on every td and th on the page, not displaying. Must be something.. Gonna try to find out and if i cant find it, f it!

Comment: If you inspect the element in Chrome, like you had done in the screenshot above, to the right side of the console, it shows you all the styles being applied to that element. See if something is preventing it from having a width of 0.

Comment: I tried, but nothing seems to get in the way. I think its the drag and drop library that I import. It works in jsfiddle, but not on my website.. guess ill leave it for now, ill mark this as an answer because it worked in jsfiddle. :)

Answer (score 1):

you must use [`jqgrid`](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx)

or just for sorting you can use [`tablesorter`](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) which is very easy to implement

Comment: I already have 2 of those kind of libraries imported (dragging and sorting) and as its just a little project I would realy like a smaller solution. My problem is the hiding of a whole column, not the sorting of it.