# Find all td elements on click of their th element

Tags: jquery, html

With jQuery, I'm trying to `$('th').click(function () {` and then find all of the `td` elements that are "under" the `th` (in the same column).

Then do something to each of the `input` elements in the `td`'s based off the value contained therein.

**html**

```
<table id="tbl_id">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="class_name1" type="text" value="foo" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name2" type="text" value="bar" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name3" type="text" value="baz" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="class_name1" type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name2" type="text" value="321" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name3" type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On clicking the `th` element, I want to be able to find each of the `td` in the same column.

Not exaclty what I was after, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702726/4442529) and was playing around with the example given to see if I could make it work for me. No luck.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is the jQuery I used on my first try, but I want to make this function work for all the columns, not just the on with the `class="class_name2"`:

```
function name () {
    $('.row').each(function () {
        var foo = $(this).find('.class_name2');
        if (foo.val().length !== 0) {
            $(this).toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is requirement to toggle visibility of `input` elements which are children of `td` elements ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. However, more like toggling the whole row's visibility if the fields in the column have a value more than zero.

Comment: Is requirement to toggle _both_  input elements whose value is greater than 0 length _and_ input elements whose value is 0 length ?

Comment: @guest271314 if `value !== 0` .

Comment: If `value !== 0` , what is expected result ? 1) entire row (_all_ `input` elements)  toggled ? 2) input elements having `value !== 0` toggled ? 3) input elements having _not_ having `value !== 0` toggled ?

Comment: @guest271314 On click of the `th`, checks *all* input elements *in that column*. We don't care about the input elements in the other columns. For all that value length `!== 0`, hides the entire row, but just based on the input in the particular column. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8jpxwtfn/2

```
$("th").click(function(){   
    var thIndex = $(this).index()+1;
    $("table td:nth-child("+ thIndex +") input").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val()!=""){
            $(this).css("background-color","red");
        }
    });
});
```

Wasn't exactly sure what you wanted to do with the inputs, so, in this case, we'll say any input in the column we select that has a value, we'll color red.

Note: this assumes that your table doesn't have colspans, rowspans, etc.

Comment: The fiddle is not working for me...could be a "user" error on my end, but please check. Thanks.

Comment: Define "not working"? :) Works for me in Chrome, IE, Firefox.

Comment: That's weird. Well, I changed the fiddle to onDomReady instead of onload. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/8jpxwtfn/2/

Comment: Ooops...that was UBD on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$("#tbl_id th").on("click", function(e) {
  var i = $(this).index();
  var res = $.map($("#tbl_id .row"), function(el, key) {   
       var elem = $(el).find("td").eq(i).find("input");
       return elem.val().length !== 0 ? elem[0] : null
  });
  
  if (res.length > 1) {
   $(res).parent().toggle()
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_id">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="class_name1" type="text" value="foo" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name2" type="text" value="bar" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name3" type="text" value="baz" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input class="class_name1" type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name2" type="text" value="321" /></td>
        <td><input class="class_name3" type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("th").click(function(){
   var table = $(this).parents("table");
   var index = $(table).find("tr th").index(this)+1;
   var tds = $(table).find(".row td:nth-of-type("+index+")");
});
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally benefit from some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("th").click(function(){
    var a = $(this).index();
    $("tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        var b = $(this).find("td:eq("+a+") input").val();
        alert(b)
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. Try to include at least a few words along with your code to make this answer more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
$("th").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var index = $this.index();
   var tdList = $this.closest("table").find("tr").find("td:eq("+index+")>input");
 });
```

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/8jpxwtfn/1/)